# solr 4.4 integration with magento - plausible?

Tags: solr

Sorry to bring up a question that has already been answered on these forums. I have noticed there is a post on these forums clearly stating that magento 1.13 only supports solr 3.6.

I've informed my architect on this and even though the official line is clear he still wants me to investigate whether or not it is feasible to hack the solr config files to get 4.4 working with magento 1.13.

I understand where he is coming from as he is concerned about supportability of an old version of solr.

In people's opinions is hacking the solr config files to try and get 4.4 working with magento 1.13 a plausible theory? Or are there other factors at play that make this not possible at all?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, 3.6 but you have more problems than that, 'hacking' core code is a techies way of trying to fix problems where the business side has not seen the necessity to fix the 'problem'. In a higher end environment, and as you are using Enterprise will have revenue in the $millions, you need to be taking a more business/technical centric approach.

Companies such as SAP have 7year cycles (Large Enterprise), Medium Enterprise will have 3.5year cycles, and Small Enterprise (which you will be in) will have 1.5-2year cycles, (Micro Enteprise have 9-12mth cycles - companies under $2million revenue per year). Basically you can run a version for 2years without needing to think about upgrading, meaning that Solr 3.6 is perfectly fine and as it will not be visitor accessed directly you can double the time.

Given the economy people are having a habit of 'finding' work. So, yes you can do it in theory from a technical perspective if you have plenty of time and patience, but from a business point of view it is pointless. It sounds like your architect is taking a Micro Enterprise approach.

Comment: You've made it sound like it is more trouble than what it is worth. Thanks for your comments/

Answer (score 1):

The SOLR library being used for the Enterprise module is not that great IMO. There is another library called Solarium ( http://www.solarium-project.org/ ) that (in my experience) is a bit more robust and polished (and is also still actively maintained).

If you're capable, I would suggest writing your own module using this library instead (I am not aware of any pre-built modules using this library, other than what I have built). It will also require the installation of another module, https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Magento-PSR-0-Autoloader .

Benefits should be obvious. You learn how it works better. You can use SOLR 4 and newer (I'm currently running with 4.5.1). The library is actively maintained and has a community and support available.

Comment: Is it possible to share the module that you have built? I am using Solr 4.10.1 and I am exploring the possibility of getting all the product data from Solr and not use it for search within Magento alone.Thanks